# Interpreting Shapiro-Wilk-Test, skewness and kurtosis in the light of a qqplot and histogram

Tags: normality-assumption, skewness, qq-plot, kurtosis

Currently I'm trying to find out if my data with n=11 follows a normal distribution to decide how I process further. To find this out I use the Shapiro-Wilk-Test which gives me p < 0.05 and thus I reject the H1. Further, I took a look on the skewness and kurtosis of my distribution.

```
Shapiro-
Wilk-Test     Skewness                   Kurtosis
W     p     Statistic SE    Z      Statistic SE     Z
0.92  0.41  0.39      0.66  0.59   -0.99     1.27   -0.78
```

As -1.96 < Z < 1.96 I reject the H1 for skewness as well for kurtosis.

Then, I took a look on the qqplot, too. While there are some points that deviate from the line, most of them are pretty close to it. Together with the values of the Shapiro-Wilk-Test, skewness, kurtosis and the qqplot I assumed that my distribution is close to normal. However, taking a look on a histogram of my distribution reveals a distribution that is not even approximately normal.

[image]

[image]

My question is if using the Shapiro-Wilk-Test, skewness and kurtosis values such few data is useless and if I interpreted the qqplot wrong and should rather stick to the histogram?

Comment: With only $n = 11$ obs, it is very difficult to say whether the population from which they were sampled is normal, uniform, exponential--or anything else. Shapiro-Wilk may reject normality, but the Q-Q plot looks fine. For such small sample sizes sample skewness and kurtosis could be almost any value (try moving **one** observation from below 50 into the gap between 110 and 130. Then recompute Shapiro-Wilk P-value, skewness and kurtosis. Almost **no** histogram of 11 obs will look normal, unless you contrive iit. // Also you haven't made it clear what "further processing "is yet to come.come.

Comment: When I tried digitizing your sample from the y-axis of your Q-Q plot and then running a Shapiro-Wilk test, I got P-value about 10%. I'm not saying you made a mistake, but my reconstructed sample can't be hugely wrong, so I suspect Shapiro-Wild doesn't say the actual sample his 'hugely' non-normal. In fact, your output seems to say it's 41% >> 5%. Maybe your question can benefit from some clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With further processing I mean which method for inference statistics I should use. I want to test for normality to decide if I have to use parametric or non-parametric tests.

Comment: Seems like I made a mistake when writing my post and I meant to say that Shapiro-Wilk gives me a p-value greater than 0.05.

So, if I understand you right, kurtosis and skewness aren't reliable for such a small sample size?

Comment: With only 11 observations you may have trouble getting a significant result from a nonparametric test. Test of what?

Comment: Significance test between control group and patient group for a given set of parameters.

Comment: seems to be a useful question. it does require redrafting.